# How to debug Gulpfile.js when running it with Visual Studio 2017 Task Runner Explorer?

Tags: asp.net, node.js, gulp, visual-studio-2017, task-runner-explorer

I'm using Gulp in ASP.NET project to perform some pre-build tasks like copying JavaScript from node_modules, minifying and combining JavaSCript and CSS, etc.
Everything is fine and elegant, except

1. Visual Studio Task Runner Explorer doesn't stop on breakpoints in
   Gulpfile.js.
2. I didn't find in which window can I see output from console.log()
   statements.